# dual monitor issue - integrated graphics

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

Dual monitor is not working.
I'm using i5-11600 integrated graphic(no other graphic card),
I guess ubuntu can't detect the monitors.

in `display setting` tap, they say `unknown display`.

Here is output of `xrandr` :

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default

Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768

default connected primary 1024 x 768+0+0 0mm x 0mm

   1024 x 768       76.0*
```

Ubuntu cant get the monitor size and there is only one monitor.

I'm using one HDMI port and one dp port.

---

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00* 
jinu@jinuPC:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
jinu@jinuPC:~$ uname -r
5.8.0-53-generic
jinu@jinuPC:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] jinu password: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff memory:6000000000-6000ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

In my guess, there are no graphic driver for my computer because linux don't support Rocket Lake(intel 11th).
Is this right?

Comment: Could you update your question to include the output of `lsb_release -a`, `uname -r`, and `sudo lshw -C video`? This will provide some information that people might aid in determining the issue.

Comment: matigo i did !!

Comment: You may want to update to 21.04, which has better support for the newest Intel processors.